# How do I print data in a tabular format in Java, without using printf/format?

Tags: java, tabular

The data length varies, so using `\t` isn't an option, since the formatting gets messed up. I have the same problem while using `printf` (since there is no fixed size for each data entry). So, is there any other way to do this, without using a third party library?

Comment: https://github.com/assylias/Java-Text-Table-Formatter - if you don't want to import a library you can copy paste the code, assuming the license is acceptable.